# Using & bindings in nested AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind to `ng-change` on an element created by a directive up through two other directives that wrap it to a method on the controller using `&` bindings in an isolate scope, but I can't figure out how to get arguments to pass all the way through. Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zcMM6FlIshy4lFohCvz9) that demonstrates the problem.

In short, I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<body ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <button ng-click="doSomething('Called directly')">Call Function Directly</button>
    <br />
    <outer on-outer-model-changed="doSomething('Called from Outer in HTML')"></outer>
  </div>
</body>
```

The controller:

```
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function(one, two, three) {
      console.log(arguments);
    };
  }
]);
```

The `outer` directive:

```
app.directive('outer', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      outerModelChanged: '&onOuterModelChanged'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var innerElement = angular.element('<inner></inner>');
      innerElement.attr('on-inner-model-changed', 'outerModelChanged(\'Called from Outer\')');
      element.after(innerElement);
      $compile(innerElement)(scope);
      console.log(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

And the `inner` directive that the `outer` directive creates:

```
app.directive('inner', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      innerModelChanged: '&onInnerModelChanged'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="innerModelChanged(\'Called from Inner\')">Call from Inner</button>'
  }
});
```

I understand that I'm getting the output `["Called from Outer in HTML"]` because this is hardcoded into the `<outer>` tag. What I don't understand is how to pass arguments all the way up from the `inner` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% get what you want to accomplish but this is how you would make the `["Called from Inner"]` message appear.

Change the html so the `on-outer-model-changed` expression does not use a hardcoded string.

```
  <body ng-app="ExampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <button ng-click="doSomething('Called directly')">Call Function Directly</button>
      <br />
      <outer on-outer-model-changed="doSomething(outerParam)"></outer>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Then change the outer directive to call `outerModelChanged` with a parameter. And set the `outerParam` to the `innerParam`.

```
app.directive('outer', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      outerModelChanged: '&onOuterModelChanged'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      var innerElement = angular.element('<inner></inner>');
      innerElement.attr('on-inner-model-changed', 'outerModelChanged({outerParam:innerParam})');
      element.after(innerElement);
      $compile(innerElement)(scope);
      console.log(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

Finally call the `innerModelChanged` from the inner directive with the `innerParam` set to your message.

```
app.directive('inner', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      innerModelChanged: '&onInnerModelChanged'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="innerModelChanged({innerParam:\'Called from Inner\'})">Call from Inner</button>'
  }
});
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/E313mIhNkzoGEkK7UtS8) to the above code.

Comment: You understand perfectly, it seems. I ended up injecting a service into the directive, which seems like a much saner approach. The changes you've suggested do exactly what I was trying to do, however.

Comment: Right on that sounds like a better approach indeed!